# Code a summary table with summarised averages based on levels of a factor (with a total column)

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like code to create a summary table where multiple means are calculated based on two criteria (i.e. levels of factor variables). These levels are in there respective columns but I would like to cut them into their own columns of a table and also create a total column (i.e. the mean of both levels combined). I have the following example code:

I want to use a table for a neat data summary for markdown and possibly convert to word.

```
Depth<-c('0',   '0.1-2.0',  '2.1-10.0', '10.1-20.0',    '20.1- 
50.0',  '50.1-100.0',   '0', '0.1-2.0', '2.1-10.0', '10.1-20.0',     
'20.1-50.0',    '50.1-100.0')
Tag<-   c('Tag.1',  'Tag.1',    'Tag.1',    'Tag.1',     
'Tag.1',    'Tag.1',    'Tag.2',    'Tag.2',    'Tag.2',     
'Tag.2',    'Tag.2',    'Tag.2')
Proportion<-    c(2.287356322,  5.896551724,    9.528735632,     
7.229885057,    73.54022989,    1.517241379,    0.5,    86.3,   13.2,    
0.1,    0.1,    0.1)
Season<-    c('Autumn', 'Autumn',   'Autumn',   'Autumn',    
'Autumn',   'Autumn',   'Summer',   'Summer',   'Summer',    
'Summer',   'Summer',   'Summer')

df<-data.frame(Depth, Tag, Proportion, Season)
```

which I can create the following table out of:

```
library(knitr)
df$Proportion<-as.numeric(df$Proportion)
df$Depth<-as.factor(df$Depth)

tt1<-df%>%
  group_by(Season, Depth)%>%
  summarise(Mean=mean(Proportion))

kable(tt1)


|Season |Depth      |      Mean|
|:------|:----------|---------:|
|Autumn |0          |  2.287356|
|Autumn |0.1-2.0    |  5.896552|
|Autumn |10.1-20.0  |  7.229885|
|Autumn |2.1-10.0   |  9.528736|
|Autumn |20.1-50.0  | 73.540230|
|Autumn |50.1-100.0 |  1.517241|
|Summer |0          |  0.500000|
|Summer |0.1-2.0    | 86.300000|
|Summer |10.1-20.0  |  0.100000|
|Summer |2.1-10.0   | 13.200000|
|Summer |20.1-50.0  |  0.100000|
|Summer |50.1-100.0 |  0.100000|
```

But further summary would benefit the reader (i.e the table would only have four columns: 1 Depth, 2 MeanAut, 3 MeanSum and 4 Total)

I have tried:

```
ttt1<-df%>%
  group_by(Depth)%>%
  mutate(meanAut=case_when(Season=='Autumn' ~ 
 summarise(mean(Proportion))))%>%
    mutate(meanSum=case_when(Season=='Summer' ~ 
summarise(mean(Proportion))))%>%
 bind_rows(summarise_all(., funs(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Total")))
```

But get error:
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')".

Expected output:

```
Depth       meanAut meanSum Total
0           2.2     NA      2.2
0.1-2.0     5.8     86.3    46.05
10.1-20.0   7.2     0.1     3.65
2.1-10.0    9.5     13.2    11.35
20.1-50.0   73.5    0.1     36.8
50.1-100.0  1.5     0.1     0.8
```

Any advice on how to format the table would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Comment: apologies, expected output now included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Depth, Season) %>%
 summarise(mean_season = mean(Proportion, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 mutate(Season = paste("Mean", Season, sep = "_")) %>%
 spread(Season, mean_season)  %>%
 left_join(df %>%
 group_by(Depth) %>%
 summarise(Mean_Total = mean(Proportion, na.rm = TRUE)),
 by = c("Depth" = "Depth"))

  Depth      Mean_Autumn Mean_Summer Mean_Total
  <fct>            <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 0                 2.29         0.5      1.39 
2 0.1-2.0           5.90        86.3     46.1  
3 10.1-20.0         7.23         0.1      3.66 
4 2.1-10.0          9.53        13.2     11.4  
5 20.1-50.0        73.5          0.1     36.8  
6 50.1-100.0        1.52         0.1      0.809
```

Here it, first, calculates the means per depths and seasons. Second, it creates the new variable names, containing "Mean". Third, it makes the new variable names into columns, with the means as values. Forth, it calculates the overall mean per depths. Finally, it combines the overall and seasonal means, joining the two on "Depth".

And with adding `kable()` from `knitr`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Depth, Season) %>%
 summarise(mean_season = mean(Proportion, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 mutate(Season = paste("Mean", Season, sep = "_")) %>%
 spread(Season, mean_season)  %>%
 left_join(df %>%
 group_by(Depth) %>%
 summarise(Mean_Total = mean(Proportion, na.rm = TRUE)),
 by = c("Depth" = "Depth")) %>%
 kable()

|Depth      | Mean_Autumn| Mean_Summer| Mean_Total|
|:----------|-----------:|-----------:|----------:|
|0          |    2.287356|         0.5|  1.3936782|
|0.1-2.0    |    5.896552|        86.3| 46.0982759|
|10.1-20.0  |    7.229885|         0.1|  3.6649425|
|2.1-10.0   |    9.528736|        13.2| 11.3643678|
|20.1-50.0  |   73.540230|         0.1| 36.8201149|
|50.1-100.0 |    1.517241|         0.1|  0.8086207|
```